# Move a list of source files with classes inside to another folder and automatically change namespace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Let's say I have 100 winforms in folder Forms. All form classes belong to ProjectName.Forms namespace. I want to move all those forms to folder WinForms and I want their namespace to change to ProjectName.WinForms.

Is there a way to do this automatically without manually changing each form's namespace? I have a Resharper, but didn't find any options that could help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the Visual Studio Replace In Files command for this.  Under the Edit menu --> Find and Replace --> Replace in files.

Next to the "Look in" dropdown, you have a builder button.  Clicking that will bring up a window where you can specify the folder you want to look in.

Here's a screenie:

[alt text http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/5472/replaceinfiles.png](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/5472/replaceinfiles.png)

Comment: There is one problem with this approach. I will have to change all references (usages) to these forms from ProjectName.Forms to ProjectName.WinForms. I mean after this 'Find&Replace' operation my project will not compile and have tens of errors "Type or namespace could not be found".

Comment: You shouldn't be using widespread fully qualified references like that anyway, for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

For these types of scenarios I usually use some shell script magic (you'd need cygwin and/or Perl or the like). Something like:

for i in *; do perl -pi -e 's/ProjectName.Forms/ProjectName.WinForms/g' $i; done

I suppose VS probably has some sort of broad search and replace functionality built in, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Replace In Files and restrict the replacement to a specific folder, and also to match to whole words which will avoid unwanted replacements.

First off, replace all 'namespace ProjectName.Forms' with 'namespace ProjectName.WinForms' then if you have any dependent code replace 'using ProjectName.Forms;' with 'using ProjectName.WinForms;' in that.

(Edit: assuming c#)